# Using TPU on Cloud ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tpu

I am trying to use TPU on Cloud ML Engine but I am at a loss as to how I should provide the `tpu` argument which `TPUClusterResolver` expects.

This is the environment I am using:

```
--python-version 3.5 \
--runtime-version 1.12 \
--region us-central1 \
--scale-tier BASIC_TPU
```

The job crashes with:

```
ValueError: Please provide a TPU Name to connect to.
```

As a separate issue - ML engine seems to be adding `--master grpc://10.129.152.2:8470` on its own to my job which also crashes the job. As a workaround for it I just added an un-used master flag to my code.

Comment: There is a `master-replica-0  Running task with arguments: --cluster... --tpu_node={"project": "nd1a3f7fc7f45c50c-ml", "zone": "us-central1-c", "tpu_node_name": "cmle-training-18374866318486238002-tpu"}` log generated. I guess the `tpu_node_name` needs to be somehow passed to `TPUClusterResolver`?

Comment: Which sample are you using? Please take a look at this working samples: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/tpu

Comment: I was using the inception sample from https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tree/master/models/experimental/inception.

I just tried the resnet sample from github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/tpu. That works great. I was able to use that as a template and update the inception code to work as well. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a known issue for runtime 1.11 and 1.12 and it has been fixed. Now, the service won't append `--master` to your training application. You should continue using `TpuClusterResolver`.